# How to remove hover function from mobile responsive screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using hover function when window normal screen

```
jQuery(".main-menu ul li").hover(
    function() {
        jQuery(this).children("ul").slideToggle(1000);
    }
```

But I want when screen will be 768px for mobile responsive this hover function don't work and click function will active. I have used this function

```
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();

        if(screenWidth <= 768){
            jQuery(".main-menu ul li").click(function() {
                jQuery(this).children("ul").slideToggle(1000);
            });

        }
    });
```

But Its don't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try after resize window unbind previous click event :

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    $( ".main-menu ul li").unbind();
    var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();

    if(screenWidth <= 768){
        jQuery(".main-menu ul li").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).children("ul").slideToggle(1000);
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: hover and click both are working by this code. I want only click function. When screen 768px. Thanks.

Comment: I missed that previous event was hover not click - maybe now it will be ok. I delete  "click" event form .unbind(); so now you will unbind all events - if this is incorrect try pass 'hover' @Musarrof

Comment: Thank you so much. You are the boss of JS.